# Insert mean into a scatter plot in R

Tags: r

I will insert two codes below, the first one generates a scatter plot that takes into account the chosen date (`date2`) in my database. The link to download the database is:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W_hzuRq7D6X12BdwaXeM-cjg2A5MIKDx/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102073768617937039119&rtpof=true&sd=true . Anyway, I'll insert my database image at the end of this message.

The second code is for calculating the mean and standard deviation with respect to the same database. In this case, they are taking into account the day of the week (`Week`). You will see in code 2 that for calculating the mean and standard deviation I entered an `i`, so if i=3, it means Saturday.

However, I would like to insert two horizontal lines: one mean and the other mean+standard deviation in my scatterplot, ie in code 1. So if I choose, for example, 10/4/2021, it will generate a scatter plot, but it would also insert the two lines I mentioned (mean and mean+standard deviation) corresponding to the chosen day of the week, which in this case is Saturday. If I choose the day 09/04/2021, it will generate the scatter plot and the lines for Friday.

I appreciate any help!

Thank you very much!

Muito obrigado!

**First code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df<-read_excel('C:/Users/Downloads/database_test.xlsx')

#create scatter plot
scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
  dta %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dt)) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
    plot(xlab = "Days", ylab = "Types", xlim = c(0, 7))
}  

scatter_date("2021-04-10",df)
```

[image]

**Seconde code**

```
 #calculation of mean and standard deviation

df<-subset(df,df$date2<df$date1) 

dim_data<-dim(df)

day<-c(seq.Date(from = as.Date(df$date2[1]),
                to = as.Date(df$date2[dim_data[1]]),
                by = "1 day"))

df_grouped<-matrix(nrow = 9,ncol=6)
colnames(df_grouped)<-c("Id","date1","date2","Week","D","D1")

df_grouped <- df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("date"), as.Date)) %>% 
  group_by(date2) %>% 
  summarise(Id = first(Id),
            date1 = first(date1),
            Week = first(Week),
            D = first(D),
            D1 = sum(D1)) %>% 
  select(Id,date1,date2,Week,D,D1)

df_grouped <- df_grouped %>% mutate(date1=format(date1,"%d/%m/%Y"),
                                    date2=format(date2,"%d/%m/%Y"))
df_grouped<-data.frame(df_grouped)

DS=c("Thursday","Friday","Saturday") 

i<-3 
df_OC<-subset(df_grouped,is.na(D)) 
ds_OC<-subset(df_OC,df_OC$Week==DS[i])

mean_Week<-mean(as.numeric(ds_OC[,"D1"]) )
mean_Week
[1] 19

sdeviation_Week<-sd(as.numeric(ds_OC[,"D1"]))
sdeviation_Week
[1] 7.071068
```

**Database**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before creating the plot, you should first compute the mean and the standard deviation with your second code. Once you have those two numbers, you can pass them to your first code `scatter_date` (you'll need new argument to your function). Inside `scatter_date` you'll need to compute the `y` range as well.

Then, inside `scatter_date` you can call the `abline` function which is made to draw horizontale lines. Here is a very small piece of code to illustrate the idea:

```
df <- data.frame(days = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), types = c(14, 15, 14, 16, 14))
mean_week <- 19
sd_week <- 7.07
y_max <- max(c(df$types, mean_week + sd_week))
y_min <- min(c(df$types, mean_week - sd_week))
plot(df, xlim = c(0, 7), ylim = c(y_min, y_max)) +
  abline(h=mean_week, col='blue') +
  abline(h=(mean_week + sd_week), col='green') +
  abline(h=(mean_week - sd_week), col='green')
```

Note: I've used `plot` because your code uses it. But I also saw that you load the `ggplot2` library. I would encourage you to use `ggplot` to create your plots instead of the base `plot` function.